# Mobile data in notification toggle

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I upgraded my Moto G 2 mobile to Android 5.0.2 Lollipop and I have been using Clean Master notification toggle. After this upgrade mobile data is not working by pressing on the mobile data symbol in notification toggle. Pressing on that is taking me to Settings > Data Usage.

Answer (score 3):

Since Lollipop, 3rd-party apps can no longer toggle mobile data without root. However, there's a handy new data toggle in the stock quick settings; tap the signal icon, then tap the toggle in the top-right.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can slide down the notification button and slide right to see more of the apps or Wi-Fi or other settings and click the data toggle. Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Install [Phone Testing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=diewland.testing.phone) app, no need to root (or input `*#*#4636#*#*` from the dialer). After install, open "Phone information", and change network mode in "Set preferred network mode". Don't change other options

For rooted devices, consider the app [Toggle Network Type 5.0 (root)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/widget-toggle-network-type-5-0-xda-t2945406) (free on XDA).

Comment: I couldn't find "Set preferred network mode" on Nexus 5, Lollipop 5.1.1, but maybe that's because it's Nexus, not Moto G2.

Answer (score -1):

Well I may have found an answer for this data toggle issue. Because I too can't live without one. But unfortunately this only works if you own a Samsung smart watch.

I downloaded 'instant settings' for my Gear S. This app allows you to control certain toggles for your phone, such as; Wi-Fi, power saving mode, sound and of course a data toggle.

Well what do you know... The data toggle actually works. I can turn my mobile data on and off by a single tap on my watch. I guess this will have to do for now.

Just thought I'd try and help out by giving you guys my solution for the time being, hope this helps. ☺